# R Code to extract values for fields out of JSON logfile

Tags: r, regex, string, extract

I have a file that contains 50,000 records from log collections.  I need to pull out the value that follows "State": & "Code": for each record.  I have tried regex but cannot get anything to work.  Instead I tried this command to see if I could get even 1 of the values, but it just times out.

```
#this never completes
sub(".*?Code(.*?);.*", "\\1", logfile
```

I don't have experience with this type of work so I appreciate any help!  Here is exactly how the logfile is formatted (supposedly JSON).  My goal would be that the following values are returned (if State & Code cannot be included that is OK):

**(State: Red, Code: Null(State: Blue, Code: no receipt)**

Below is the exact syntax of the **logfile** with 2 records:

```
 "
    2020-05-12 00:07:00.9681200, z123-asddfas,"
    ========== mode for SKU ==========
    ========== Records found ==========
    No records found
    ========== DRecords found ==========
    No drecords found
    "
    2020-05-12 00:08:46.5076411,qwer98-asdha,"
    ========== mode for SKU ==========
    ========== records found ==========
    {
        "State":  "Red",
        "Code":  null
    }
    ========== DRecords found ==========
    No drecords found
    "
    2020-05-12 00:10:02.6607640,qweaso-34324-asda,"
    ========== mode for SKU ==========
    ========== records found ==========
    {
        "State":  "Blue",
        "Code":  "no receipt"
    }
```

Comment: Try `stringr::str_extract_all(x, '(?<="Code":\\s{0,3})(?:"[^"]*"|null)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in your text

```
logIn <-  read_lines('"
    2020-05-12 00:07:00.9681200, z123-asddfas,"
========== mode for SKU ==========
  ========== Records found ==========
  No records found
========== DRecords found ==========
  No drecords found
"
    2020-05-12 00:08:46.5076411,qwer98-asdha,"
========== mode for SKU ==========
  ========== records found ==========
  {
    "State":  "Red",
    "Code":  null
  }
========== DRecords found ==========
  No drecords found
"
    2020-05-12 00:10:02.6607640,qweaso-34324-asda,"
========== mode for SKU ==========
  ========== records found ==========
  {
    "State":  "Blue",
    "Code":  "no receipt"
  }')
```

Put it into wrangleable form, clean it up, and filter

```
@library(tidyverse)    
tibble(lines = logIn) %>% 
     # Keep only the lines with 'state' or 'code'
  filter(str_detect(lines, "(?ix) ( state | code )")) %>% 
     # Clean out all the whitespace and punct, except the ':'
  mutate(lines = str_replace_all(lines, '["\\s,]', '')) %>% 
     # Use separate to divide into two new columns
  separate(lines, c("ATTR", "VALUE"), sep = ":")
```

What did we get?

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ATTR  VALUE    
  <chr> <chr>    
1 State Red      
2 Code  null     
3 State Blue     
4 Code  noreceipt
```

##################### BY REQUEST

```
tibble(lines = logIn) %>% 
  # Keep only the lines with 'state' or 'code'
  filter(str_detect(lines, "(?ix) ( state | code )")) %>% 
    # This ID will come in useful
  rowid_to_column("ID") %>% 
  # Clean out all the whitespace and punct, except the ':'
  mutate(lines = str_replace_all(lines, '["\\s,]', ''),
         # Give each State and Code the same ID.
         ID = floor((ID + 1) / 2)) %>% 
  # Use separate to divide into two new columns
  separate(lines, c("ATTR", "VALUE"), sep = ":") %>% 
    # spread take it from longform to wideform
  spread(key = ATTR, value = VALUE) %>% 
  select(ID, State, Code)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
     ID State Code     
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>    
1     1 Red   null     
2     2 Blue  noreceipt
```

Comment: This worked perfectly--Thank you!  Is there a simple way to keep the Values together by row?  So the columns would be State & Code and each row contains the values.  I was looking at options for separate but couldn't find the right combo.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you for sharing this!